# Is it possible to set the date/time on a Fedora 14 server and have it retain the setting on reboot

Tags: fedora, time

I've successfully set the date/time and, after reboot, it is reset [or, at least, off].

I use Linode to host the F14 VPS.

Fix: set proper time zone in /etc/sysconfig/clock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your timezone set correctly? With Linode (and most Xen kernels) the DomUs will automatically get their time from the Dom0. Linode has all of their Dom0 hypervisors running ntpd, so their time should be accurate. As such, it's likely that you just need to set your timezone correctly and everything should be good.

If you want to "untether" your VPS's clock from the host's clock, set the following in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
xen.independent_wallclock=1
```

After this change, you'll either need to reboot for it to take effect or else run the following:

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/xen/independent_wallclock
```

Also, if you haven't already done so, make sure to set the TZ correctly in `/etc/sysconfig/clock`.

Comment: "I Think" it is set correctly. I set the time zone to MST [cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/MST /etc/localtime] and set the time. Am I missing a step.?

Comment: What is the output of `date`, and what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: OUtput of date: Sun Jan  1 03:23:15 UTC 2012

Comment: Then you haven't set the timezone correctly - the system is still using UTC.

Comment: Output expected: Sat Dec  31 20:23:15 MST 2011

Comment: I can set the time zone and all will be fine, until reboot. Which is rare but I feel like I am doing something wrong since each time I have to change the time zone back.

Comment: Give `/usr/bin/system-config-date` a try.

Comment: Installing it now, will give it  shot. Thank you, Erik.

Comment: Can only access the server through ssh, can't use the GUI. I went ahead and set the time zone again. I'll have to make a note to check the time zone after each reboot. Again, thank you, ErikA

Comment: Actually - try setting the TZ in `/etc/sysconfig/clock`.

Comment: That may have done the trick. It was set to America/New York. :)

Comment: Awesome - great to hear. Happy New Year.